# JSON ISO 8601 time string to time format AWS-Glue

Tags: aws-glue

I have JSON formatted data that has an ISO 8601 timestamp format in it example  "2017-06-29T00:00:00-0400"  and I am trying to use AWS Glue to transform for Athena/Quicksights use; however every combination of conversion I have tried still sees the destination field as a string (after crawling the destination json file).  I also receive a HIVE_BAD_DATA error parsing field when trying to query against the table in Athena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the input, I was able to work around my issue by creating a calculated field in Quicksight baseed on the string using  parseDate(replace(substring({date_in_ISO},1,19),'T'," "),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set timestamp.formats=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+|-hhmm in serde parameter section of the table definition. You can do this in AWS Glue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> df = df.withColumn("isodate", to_timestamp("isodate",
>   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))